# Include a canvasJS chart in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvasjs

I don't know why I can't include a canvasJS with JavaScript on another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='btn']").click(function() {
            var vValue = document.getElementById("value").value;
            var testValue = document.getElementById("test").value;
            var projValue = document.getElementById("project").value;               
            $("#parent").load('/index.php/grafic/view/proiect1/1/2');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I use those values (vValue, testValue, projValue) but in this case I was trying a test: if the values are correct I use an `.alert()` to see if it takes these values.
On the page index.php/grafic/view/project1/1/2 I have a canvasJS graphic that works if I enter on that page.

A part of my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                        {
                            exportEnabled: true,
                            title:{
                                text: "<?php echo $nume; ?>"
                            },
                            axisY:{
                                title:"Number of runs"
                            },
                            legend: {
                            ---//---


                             </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/css/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
            <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 1100px;"></div>
```

So my problem is that after I click the button, in the parent div that chart will not appear, but if I write some text on that page, it will show in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that you are using window.onload and this function never will be executed because the page is loading by ajax(.load function)
Try to use jquery load-event instead